# Add an element with addEventListener and get it in the next iteration

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, dom, addeventlistener

I add an eventlistener on all html element with the class "card-title", this listener serve to create the same html element with the class "card-title", but these new element created don't respond to the addEventListener when I click on them. I guess it's because they are not added to the array cardTitles and I don't know how to do it

```
function myFunc() {
  var cardTitles = document.getElementsByClassName('card--title');

  for (var i = 0; i < cardTitles.length; i++) {
    cardTitles[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
      var newCard = document.createElement('p');
      newCard.className = 'card--title';
      newCard.innerText = 'Enter';
      document.body.appendChild(newCard);
    });
  }
}

myFunc();
```

Comment: Use event delegation: `document.addEventListener("click", function(e){ if(e.target.matches(".card--title")){ /* Do click listener things */ } })`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I guess it's because they are not added to the array cardTitles and I don't know how to do it

Actually, they are (if `getElementsByClassName` is natively supported by the browser, not polyfilled); it returns a **live** `HTMLCollection`.

What *isn't* happening, though, is that you're not hooking the event listener on those new elements. Your loop only runs once, handling the elements that are there **then**, it isn't re-run when you add elements.

You have two choices:

1. Add the handler to each new element when you add the element, or
2. Use a **single** handler on the container all of these are in, and use `event.target` to figure out which one was clicked, since clicks bubble; this is called *event delegation*

Here's a quick example of #1:

```
function myFunc() {
  function handler() {
    var newCard = document.createElement('p');
    newCard.className = 'card--title';
    newCard.innerText = 'Enter';
    newCard.addEventListener('click', handler);
    document.body.appendChild(newCard);
  }

  var cardTitles = document.getElementsByClassName('card--title');

  for (var i = 0; i < cardTitles.length; i++) {
    cardTitles[i].addEventListener('click', handler);
  }
}

myFunc();
```

Here's a quick example of #2:

```
function myFunc() {
  var container = document.querySelector("selector-for-the-container");
  // For your use case, you probably can just use `document.body` instead
  // of `container`, since you're appending new card titles to `document.body`

  container.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    var cardTitle = event.target.closest(".card--title");
    if (cardTitle && this.contains(cardTitle)) {
      var newCard = document.createElement('p');
      newCard.className = 'card--title';
      newCard.innerText = 'Enter';
      document.body.appendChild(newCard);
    }
  });
}

myFunc();
```

That uses [`Element#closest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest), which you'd have to polyfill if you need to support any version of IE; see the link for details.

Also note that the `&& this.contains(cardTitle)` part can be omitted if you want to handle all `.card--title` elements even if they are in an ancestor of the container you hooked the event on. I included it for completeness, but given you're appending new ones to `document.body`, you don't need it in this specific use case.

Comment: Something about the question made me not think of the duplicate, but I think Xufox and Zakaria are probably right. Can't delete; made it a CW.